# Spring Security 3.1 and Unsecured HTTP Channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We just recently upgraded from Spring Security version 3.0 to version 3.1.  Our old configuration file was apparently using a deprecated feature where you can disable security for <intercept-url> blocks within the <http> block using the 'filter="none"' option.  Here's a snippet from our old applicationContext-security.xml file:

```
<http ...>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword" filter="none" requires-channel="https" />
</http>
```

Spring Security 3.1 forces you to define additional <http> blocks to turn off security for certain URL patterns:

```
<http security="none" pattern="/resetPassword" />
```

Question: How do I force the HTTPS channel for this new <http> block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration you were using was not actually requiring https, because filters="none" means that Spring Security should not pay attention to that request. Instead for both Spring Security 3 and 3.1 you should use something like:

```
  <http use-expressions="true" ...>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
  </http>
```

Comment: Thanks!  With some other small tweaks -- namely, using hasAnyAuthority(...Roles...) instead of naming the roles directly -- and this worked beautifully.